# Flutter Push Notification using firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to send push notifications in flutter app. Able to receive the message but how to navigate to particular page on click of that notification in flutter (how to give "click-action" and needs to be done in flutter app)

This is the body we are sending in the rest api call

```
{
"orderDetails": {
    "_id": "5f5f95b4096177cb48de946e",
    "id": "BHOOKYORDER114",
    "status": "success",
    "orderStatus": "pickup pending",
    "paymentIntentId": "pi_1HRKF6IQ7vUopzpNQOJgUL8C",
    "fcmMessages": [
        {
            "type": "merchant",
            "fcmNotification": {
                "message": {
                    "data": {
                        "orderId": "5f5f95b4096177cb48de946e"
                    },
                    "notification": {
                        "title": "orderDetails",
                        "body": "You have got an order"
                    },
                    "android": {
                        "notification": {
                            "title": "orderDetails",
                            "body": "You have got an order",
                            "click_action": ".screens.order_detail_screen"
                        }
                    },
                    "token": "cwOI_6uxkKM:APA91bHIu3sSY9IhVuIP6cflm1ZdGcq_yKck741IiRrFSc1RnjYqJUlsaTiKVg6uintQfC-UoCQ4TOVBqdLhlUpdtsFy2nFOXLGAMk_3X9R_0x0VZ5MGcl5Lno3GJpljDh2nSISRFdDA"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A few things here:

```
{
"orderDetails": {
    "_id": "5f5f95b4096177cb48de946e",
    "id": "BHOOKYORDER114",
    "status": "success",
    "orderStatus": "pickup pending",
    "paymentIntentId": "pi_1HRKF6IQ7vUopzpNQOJgUL8C",
    "fcmMessages": [
        {
            "type": "merchant",
            "fcmNotification": {
                "message": {
                    "data": {
                        "orderId": "5f5f95b4096177cb48de946e",
                        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                    },
                    "notification": {
                        "title": "orderDetails",
                        "body": "You have got an order"
                    },
                    "android": {
                        "notification": {
                            "title": "orderDetails",
                            "body": "You have got an order"
                        }
                    },
                    "token": "cwOI_6uxkKM:APA91bHIu3sSY9IhVuIP6cflm1ZdGcq_yKck741IiRrFSc1RnjYqJUlsaTiKVg6uintQfC-UoCQ4TOVBqdLhlUpdtsFy2nFOXLGAMk_3X9R_0x0VZ5MGcl5Lno3GJpljDh2nSISRFdDA"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

1- click_action has to be set to "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

2- click_action has to be set in the data section of a payload

This should allow you to receive the message in the onMessage handler in your flutter app.

From there you can call Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(message['screen']).

If you don't have a BuildContext at that point, you can register a GlobalKey as the navigatorKey property of your MaterialApp, and use it to access your Navigator globally, via GlobalKey.currentState

Comment: Little late but thank you for your answer.